# image pop up problem

Tags: css, html

When you hover or click on an image within the webpage a pop up appears. However, this new pop up image is hidden behind the div to the right. Is there any way of bringing it forward so it is visible instead? Thanks in advance.

Paul

Comment: I still get an Error 403 - Forbidden and can't view the page.

Comment: It worked for me at the last but then I had something to do. :P glad you got it resolved though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div with more z-index will appear above the the one with lower z-index.
Add z-index to your style class or  quote as inline style to the div;

```
.in_style {
background-color: #E0EAF1;
white-space: nowrap;
z-index: 300;
}
 or
<div id='upperDiv' style='z-index:300;'>

        Your contents

</div>
```

Comment: the <div id='upperDiv' style='z-index:300;'> worked perfectly. Thank you so much.